# Is in If condition the check obj == null more performance effective then obj!=null

Tags: java, performance, null

According to one of my senior coding style 2 is better in performance  than coding style 1,is it true ?

coding style 1

```
If (obj!=null)
{
   Logic A
}

else
{
   Logic B
}
```

coding style 2

```
If (obj==null)
{
   Logic B
}

else
{
   Logic A
}
```

Comment: coding style 2 is better in performance than coding style 2 ????????????

Comment: If you are using Java (any high level language), chances are extremely slim that any difference will matter.

Comment: Why didn't you ask immediately to the senior ?

Comment: Do not tune performance on such a micro level. Write code that is self-expressing, do not butcher the readability of your code for micro performance.

Comment: Yep, it's slightly faster to check nullity rather than non nullity but LionC@ is right, readability must be preferred over such small improvement

Comment: I found the question title is a bit difficult to understand.

Answer (score 5):

In examples like this, it is developer performance you should worry about.  What is the cleanest and simplest code and this will often be a pattern the JIT optimiser will do a good job, if not it's best job with.

In this example, even if you could measure a difference I would suspect

- your test is broken.
- the difference would be different on different machines or JVMs.
- such a  difference will disappear in future versions of Java.

BTW: Looking at the byte code is a very poor measure of performance, but I can say that the byte code generates and I suspect the native code generated will be the same length.

Answer (score 2):

Whether or not it is faster to test for null or non-null can only be observed at the *machine code* level, which you have almost no control over. Your Java file will be compiled to bytecode and then, at runtime, this bytecode will be compiled again to machine code by the Just-in-Time compiler (JIT). The JIT performs all kids of advanced optimizations, one of which could be the reordering of branches with inversion of branching conditions.

Note that the CPU cycles spent on testing the value of the variable will be dwarfed by the penalty in branch misprediction, so correct branch prediction is the JIT compiler's foremest concern. You have absolutely zero control of these subtleties on the level of Java source code.

Therefore the unanimous advice is to take care to write code which reads most naturally and don't spend a second thinking on the peformance differential of branch ordering.

Answer (score 1):

Performance should not make a difference as *Peter Lawrey* pointed out.

I guess your friend didn't talk about performance but about **coding style**.

When using `if else`constructs people often find it preferable to first handle the non-negated case in the `if` block before handling the negated case in the `else` block.

So one better writes

```
if (a == b) {
    logicA();
}
else {
    logicB();
}
```

instead of writing

```
if (a != b) {
    logicB();
}
else {
    logicA();
}
```

as it usually leads to **better readability**.

Comment: But the `a != null` is the *non-negated* case because `a == null` actually means "there is no `a`".

Comment: You can argument like that. I rather read _a is not equal to `null`_. I usually try to avoid negated conditions, so I usually do check for `if (a == null)` first before handling the negated case.

Comment: Doesn't that then make your answer opinion-based? Anyway, most of the time I don't write either because `a == null` usually means an early return so I just write `if (a == null) return false;` or similar.

Comment: My answer shall not give my opinion but rather another point of view to the asker. As he claims his friend to be a "senior" developer he might have indeed talked about coding style rather than performance.

Comment: OP didn't leave this open to guessing: his senior colleague talked about `better in performance`.

Comment: He talked about *coding style* anyway

Comment: He talked about the *difference in performance between these two coding styles*.

Comment: So what do you suggest now?

Comment: If you want, we can [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60074/discussion-between-marko-topolnik-and-lars-blumberg).

Answer (score 0):

Your senior should provide "measurable" test cases to prove to you which logic is better.

You shouldn't worry about optimization logic as the compiler does all the optimization for you. Rather, focus on readability of code (and flow logic?). Example, Java 7 introduced [`<T> T Objects.requireNotNull(T obj)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull(T)) method, which internally does:

```
if (obj == null) {
    throw new NullPointerException();
}

return x;
```

Which is better, especially when creating API's as you have a business logic that "asserts"/guarantees not null.